# How to represent the movement trajectory of an object using CnosDB?

Tags: rust, postgis, cnosdb

I want to use CnosDB to represent the movement trajectory of an object, like this (x, y, t). It would be even better if I could calculate the movement speed based on the coordinates. In PostgreSQL, there is a geometry type that allows convenient storage. However, I found that CnosDB does not support such a data type. Currently, I am using the following statement to create the table in CnosDB

```
create table test(
  x double,
  y double,
  tags(name)
);
```

Is there a better solution? Ideally, I would like to use the following schema:

```
create table test(
  location geometry,
  tags(name)
);
```